# Copy Kentico's production database to development

Tags: c#, sql-server, kentico, kentico-mvc

We have Kentico 11.0.26 with MVC.

Was trying to set up a development instance of Kentico database by copying the production tables. Created new database using SSMS, and then using import data wizard to copy tables. No errors occurred, probably because of new database.

Had to change connection string because development SQL Server does not accept SQL authentication. New connection string:

```
   <add name="CMSConnectionString" connectionString="Server=sql-server;Database=Kentico_DB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=True; Connection Timeout=30;" />
```

Seems like I can log in with admin account but get this error right after:

> [Exception: [SimpleDataClass.AddIDWhere]: The object is missing the ID
>   column '' value, the operation cannot be performed.]
>   CMS.DataEngine.SimpleDataClass.AddIDWhere(DataQuery q, String
>   columnName) +153    CMS.DataEngine.SimpleDataClass.Update() +377
>   CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoBase`1.UpdateData() +341
>
>   CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`3.SetInfo(TInfo info) +761
>   CMS.Membership.UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfoInternal(UserInfo user)
>   +601    CMS.Membership.AuthenticationHelper.FinalizeAuthenticationProcess(UserInfo
>   user, Int32 siteId) +273
>   CMS.Membership.AuthenticationHelper.AuthenticateUser(String userName,
>   String password, String siteName, Boolean login,
>   AuthenticationSourceEnum source) +1478
>   CMS.MembershipProvider.CMSMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String
>   username, String password) +48
>   CMSPages_logon.Login1_Authenticate(Object sender,
>   AuthenticateEventArgs e) in
>   C:\path-to-kentico-cms\CMS\CMSPages\logon.aspx.cs:500
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +155
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs
>   e) +111    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs args) +50    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5445

Comment: Why not create a Full and Complete Backup of the PROD database and then restore it in your DEV Environment instead? This way all keys, indexes, etc are preserved in the DEV Database.

Comment: I was able to use your instructions and some online articles to create an Azure backpac file from production Kentico, download it locally (SSMS v18 allows you to connect to Azure storage directly) and use SSMS to import data-tier application. You have to right click Databases node in SSMS for the "Import Data-tier Application" option to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can export the DB from azure to BLOB as azure will give you .bacpac file.

Then you can restore the file using SSMS by Import Data-Tier application.